# Unhandled exception: type 'A' is not a subtype of type 'A' of 'x' where A is from

Tags: dart

I get a runtime error that reads something like this:

```
Unhandled exception:
type 'A' is not a subtype of type 'A' of 'x' where
  A is from file:///path/to/source/a.dart
  A is from package:my_package/a.dart
```

`A` is *the exact same type* as the other `A` -- there is no naming conflict.

The two indented lines ('A is from ...') only differ in their way of specifying the path. One goes through 'package:' and the second one is the file path on the file system.

Comment: This only happens when running in checked mode (`dart --checked file.dart`). IntelliJ WebStorm does that by default when you run a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR:

Use `import 'package:...'` everywhere, even when importing files from your own package.

## Explanation:

The two URLs (`file:///...` and `package:...`) are equivalent but Dart has no way of knowing that. When you import source via both relative path and via the `package:` scheme, you'll get this error.

To fix this issue, make sure to be consistent in how you import files in your own package.

## Wrong:

In file foo.dart:

```
import '../path/to/a.dart';
```

In file bar.dart:

```
import 'package:my_package/a.dart';
```

This results in an error.

## Correct:

In file foo.dart:

```
import 'package:my_package/a.dart';
```

In file bar.dart:

```
import 'package:my_package/a.dart';
```

This will be fine.

Comment: Never heard that `import '../path/to/a.dart';` causes issues as long as not reaching out from `lib` or `web` or similar top-level dirs

Comment: Ugh, just spent 20 minutes looking at this problem in my code. In one of my local named imports I had a double slash `//` <sigh/>